# Some questions about the usage of the Hunspell data format in the Hungarian Hunspell dictionary?

Tags: format, spell-checking, hunspell

After reading through the [Hunspell docs](https://sourceforge.net/projects/hunspell/files/Hunspell/Documentation/), I started looking at the seemingly most advanced instance of a set of Hunspell dictionary files, and it seems the Hungarian one (Hun-garian Spell) is the most robust.

- [`hu_HU.aff`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LibreOffice/dictionaries/master/hu_HU/hu_HU.aff)
- [`hu_HU.dic`](https://github.com/LibreOffice/dictionaries/blob/master/hu_HU/hu_HU.dic)

I have a few questions that seem to be unanswered by the 17 page PDF docs (which are the only real resource on Hunspell it appears, other than the [source code](https://github.com/hunspell/hunspell)).

##### 1. The meaning of the decimal numbers?

For example, the number `1547`. We see it here:

```
AF @ # 1547
```

And it is used in PFX but not SFX:

```
PFX r 0 legújra/1547 . 24583
PFX r 0 legújjá/1547 . 24584
PFX r 0 legössze/1547 . 24585
PFX r 0 legát/1547 . 24586
PFX r 0 legáltal/1547 . 24587
PFX r 0 legvégig/1547 . 24588
PFX r 0 legvégbe/1547 . 24589
...
```

The thing after the slash is a **flag** as far as I learned, but where is that flag defined? The line `AF @ # 1547` has 1547 as a comment, so not sure. Looking further at `AF` it appears the first line of `AF 1548` means there are 1548 AF values that follow, and `AF @` is the second to last one in the list, so maybe that's it?!

So then when does the `@` symbol mean in regards to `AF`, which is said to be:

> Hunspell can substitute affix flag sets with ordinal numbers in affix rules (alias compression, see `makealias` tool).

I'm not following....

##### 2. The meaning of the last decimal numbers on `PFX`?

Like we have from above:

```
PFX r 0 legát/1547 . 24586
```

That is the only place `24586` appears in the `.aff` file. So what does it mean? Same for all the numbers in that position. [Line #24586 in the `.dic` file](https://github.com/LibreOffice/dictionaries/blob/master/hu_HU/hu_HU.dic#L24586) doesn't seem related either:

```
lódenkabát/39   1
```

##### What do the `/number` mean in the `.dic` file?

Regarding that last example:

```
lódenkabát/39   1
```

What does `/39` and the `1` mean? Where are those defined, I would have assumed to find a `PFX 39` or `SFX 39` defined in the `.aff` file, but I don't seem to see that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learned more by looking at the tests around [alias2.aff](https://github.com/hunspell/hunspell/blob/master/tests/alias2.aff) (and other alias2 files):

### Files

**alias2.aff**:

```
AF 2
AF AB
AF A

AM 3
AM is:affix_x
AM ds:affix_y
AM po:noun xx:other_data

SFX A Y 1
SFX A 0 x . 1

SFX B Y 1
SFX B 0 y/2 . 2
```

**alias2.dic**:

```
1
foo/1   3
```

**alias2.good**:

```
foo
foox
fooy
fooyx
```

**alias2.morph**:

```
> foo
analyze(foo) =  st:foo po:noun xx:other_data
stem(foo) = foo
> foox
analyze(foox) =  st:foo po:noun xx:other_data is:affix_x
stem(foox) = foo
> fooy
analyze(fooy) =  st:foo po:noun xx:other_data ds:affix_y
stem(fooy) = fooy
> fooyx
analyze(fooyx) =  st:foo po:noun xx:other_data ds:affix_y is:affix_x
stem(fooyx) = fooy
```

### Explanation

#### Explaining the `AM`

Stands for "morphological alias"?

So this is saying we are dealing with line numbers relative to when the `AM` and `AF` start! That is crazy to me, so brittle. But anyways....

```
SFX A 0 x . 1
```

That `1` is referring to `AM morphological_fields` (from the docs). So it is marking this suffix as `AM 1` which is the first AM: `is:affix_x`. That corresponds to our `alias2.morph` file, where it shows:

```
> foox
analyze(foox) =  st:foo po:noun xx:other_data is:affix_x
stem(foox) = foo
```

Notice the `is:affix_x`.

Now, `foox` has more. This is because in the `.dic` file, it says:

```
foo/1   3
```

That `3` is pointing to another AM, which is the last one.

```
po:noun xx:other_data
```

So that gives us all three of the AMs shown in the `alias2.morph`:

```
po:noun xx:other_data is:affix_x
```

#### Explaining the `AF`

Stands for "affix flag".

The `/1` here in the `.dic` references the AF position:

```
foo/1
```

And the `/2` in the `.aff` does as well:

```
SFX B 0 y/2 . 2
```

So for the `y/2`, that is saying that `y` can come after suffix `x`, since `2` links to `AF 2` which is `AF A`, which is linking to `SFX A`, which is the `x` suffix.

I'm a bit confused at `foo/1`, which is an alias to `foo/AB`, couldn't you just write `foo/A` and it knows to allow `foo/AB` because of the `y/2` definition? Or `foo/1` / `foo/AB` must be saying `foo/A and foo/B allowed`, but `foo/B` is only allowed after `foo/A`, as per the `SFX B` definition. That must be it.